# ddp.js how to get connection id

Tags: meteor, ddp

Hi guys I am writing a meteor app and using the ddp.js v0.6.0 to make my frontend with static html. Now I need a way to get my session connection id in the front with ddp.js, is there anyway to do it? In meteor I can just do `Meteor.connection._lastSessionId`, is there any equivalent of this in ddp.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DDP.prototype._on_connected = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  var firstCon = self._reconnect_count === 0;
  var eventName = firstCon ? "connected" : "reconnected";
  self.readyState = 1;
  self._reconnect_count = 0;
  self._reconnect_incremental_timer = 0;
```

**

```
// Set the session ID here
  self.sessionId = data.session;
```

**

```
var length = self._queue.length;
  for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
    self._send(self._queue.shift());
  }
  self._emit(eventName, data);
  // Set up keepalive ping-s
  self._ping_interval_handle = setInterval(function () {
    var id = uniqueId();
    self._send({
      msg: "ping",
      id: id
    });
  }, self._ping_interval);
};
```

This is how it can be done.

https://forums.meteor.com/t/ddp-js-get-connection-id/29136/4